# How to randomly split a dataset into training set, test set, and dev set in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a large dataset and want to randomly split the dataset into 70% train, 25% test, and 5% dev. How can I do this in Python with scikit-learn?

I wonder if we do this using the sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split(*arrays, **options) function like the example in the following link?

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html

Comment: I do not think we have a direct way or API to do the same. However, you can do a double split. First use train_test_split with 30% as test. Now on this new test data, do a one more split with test size as 5% to get the dev split.

Comment: Maybe a function random.shuffle helps?
Next, you may simply slice your set in 0.7, 0.95 etc.

Answer (score 3):

Good question - it can be done with sklearn using two consecutive splits:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

X = np.random.random((10000, 10))
y = np.random.random(10000)

test_size = 0.25
holdout_size = 0.05

X_train, X_temp, y_train, y_temp = train_test_split(X, y, 
                                     test_size = test_size + holdout_size)

X_test, X_holdout, y_test, y_holdout = train_test_split(X_temp, y_temp,
                         test_size = holdout_size / (test_size + holdout_size))

print len(X_train)   # => 7000
print len(X_test)    # => 2499
print len(X_holdout) # => 501
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
from numpy.random import multinomial

n_total_samples = 1000 # or whatever it is

indices = np.arange(n_total_samples)
inds_split = multinomial(n=1,
                         pvals=[0.7, 0.25, 0.05],
                         size=n_total_samples).argmax(axis=1)

train_inds = indices[inds_split==0]
test_inds  = indices[inds_split==1]
dev_inds   = indices[inds_split==2]

print len(train_inds) / float(n_total_samples) # => 0.713
print len(test_inds) / float(n_total_samples)  # => 0.24
print len(dev_inds) / float(n_total_samples)   # => 0.047
```

It's not as pretty as a built-in function, but I believe it does what you need.

Comment: Which line in your code indicates that this is a random split? Thanks.

Comment: `multinomial` generates a random indicator vector for each data sample. Essentially, we are using the outcome of each random indicator vector for each sample to assign its index to be in the training, test, or dev set with the prescribed probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just a simple random.shuffle ? Then slice it up according to your needs.

Should look like :

```
import random
random.shuffle(yourTestSet)
```

Will, as it's name implies, randomly rearrange your samples.

```
train_set, test_set, dev_set = yourTestSet[:70], yourTestSet[70:95], yourTestSet[95:]
```

This code above works for 100 samples, adjust numbers to your needs or use len()*x if you don't know the exact size.

Edit : Suggested by  fafnir1990 in comment.